# Make a page-width div on Reveal.JS presentation

Tags: css, reveal.js

In a [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) presentation I want my `div` containing the main `h2` for the slide to have a page-wide transparent background. So far I have this css:

```
section div.haikubar {
  padding: 60px 10px 60px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 0px 200px;
}
```

I have tried `width: 100%` and several other things but the "bar" never extends the full-width of the page. It's centered and the slide background shows on each side.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ivanoats/pen/zwDEm) of cut/paste from the built presentation which has most of the HTML/CSS/JS.

Any ideas on what I can use to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is that you want your div to take up the entire width of the window, then I believe I had a similar problem and I solved it in the following manner.

By setting `width: 100%;` in css, the div will take up 100% of the slide width based on how reveal.js has been configured to display the slide. For the default configuration this means that the the slide may not be spanning the entire width of the window.

If you open Reveal.js you will be able to find and modify the configuration defaults:

```
// Configuration defaults, can be overridden at initialization time
        config = {

            // The "normal" size of the presentation, aspect ratio will be preserved
            // when the presentation is scaled to fit different resolutions
            width: 960,
            height: 700,

            // Factor of the display size that should remain empty around the content
            margin: 0.1,
```

By changing the aspect ratio and margin to:  `width:1920, height:1024, margin:0,`  I was able to get each slide to span the entire width of the window.

You may have to play around with these values depending on your intended output screen, but hopefully this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `width: '100%'`:

```
Reveal.initialize({
  // The "normal" size of the presentation, aspect ratio will
  // be preserved when the presentation is scaled to fit different
  // resolutions. Can be specified using percentage units.
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',

  // Factor of the display size that should remain empty around
  // the content
  margin: 0.04,

  // Bounds for smallest/largest possible scale to apply to content
  minScale: 0.2,
  maxScale: 2.0
});
```